# how to increase current in this given circuit

Tags: power-supply, current

I am am a beginner to this not having background from this feild  n i I have a transformer less circuit which gives out 12vdc and 30 mamp  how to increase the current to 2 amp 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, and most important, this circuit is not safe. A mistake putting it together can kill you or someone else. Do not use it for anything.

It definitely will not work well at 2 amps. Zener diode regulators work by converting the extra current capacity of the power supply to heat. 2 amps at 12 volts is a huge amount of power to waste.

Passerby's answer is the right one. Buy an AC-DC converter. Don't try to build your own if you don't have the knowledge.

Comment: By unsafe u mean it needs an enclosure and not touching while its working

Comment: A *grounded* enclosure that you don't touch is a bare minimum. A short circuit could still connect 230 volts to the outputs. To make it safer, you need a transformer.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution, cut that circuit out, and use a commercial 120/240V mains to 12V 2 Amp power supply. Its not feasible to modify the existing circuit.

Comment: Cant use that becos i have to make it on my own

Answer (score 1):

Not using that circuit!

At the moment it is the 0.47 uF capacitor that is dropping about 220V AC across it (due to its reactance). Using a bit of handwaving you could argue that the current taken from the AC is ~30mA AC therefore the reactance of the capacitor is 220/0.03 = 7333 ohms. This would be a capacitance of 0.434 uF at 50 Hz.

To take 2A, you need a capacitor that has a value that is 2/0.03 times higher i.e. about 30uF and rated at 450V. How big is one of these?

Here's one: -

[image]

I suggest you go researching on on ebay to get it's large dimensions. Please not that it cannot be an electrolytic type.

Then you need to consider that off-load the 2A is flowing into the zener diode - you'll need a zener diode rated at about 30 watts. The one below is rated at 25 watts and will require a sizable heatsink: -

[image]

Comment: It is very big in size it comes in a category of ac motor capacitor any other method ?

Comment: I have heard that we can increase the current by reducing resistance how can we apply that on this

Comment: The 0.47uF capacitor is the component that is important here - it drops the voltage and regulates the current. That is why I have said that the capacitor would need to increase by nearly 70 times to accomadate 2A.

Comment: Other methods - use a transformer or an off-line switch mode power supply - there are NO OTHER feasible methods.