# How to make a 240v ac to 12v 2amp dc transformerless step down circuit

Tags: safety, diy, reliability, step-down

I want to make a 100-240vac to 12vdc 2amp  transformerless stepdown circuit any safe reliable circuit digram is accepted

Comment: What is the prize for winning the design competition?

Comment: A vote and compliment in the comment on your ans thats the best i can do

Comment: There is no safe way to do it without a transformer. Even off-line switchers use a power supply for 24 watts.

Comment: Questions requiring a schematic are closed.

Comment: You did 0 work yourself and then ask us to just design you something. I'm with Leon. This isn't Freelancer.com, this is a volunteer Q&A site where people help, not work for free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to increase current in this given circuit](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204346/how-to-increase-current-in-this-given-circuit)

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate of his other question, where he doesn't want to accept the answers: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204346/how-to-increase-current-in-this-given-circuit

Comment: I accepted the answers on that and i have not forced anyone on this if one can tell he can if not then leave it why you are making a issue i realy dont know how to make that so i just asked simple its on u to give ans  noone is forcing u

Comment: If what you asked for was even reasonable, it would be quite a complex design task. It's not reasonable for reasons you wouldn't understand (as a beginner) if I tried to explain them. Your question demonstrates zero effort on your part and asks for a completed design. It's annoying. That's why you're catching crap for it.

Comment: Ohh thats why sorry i didnt realy knew that but i would have realy done that myself if i knew how to do that. Thanks daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This circuit should work...

[image: schematic]

Where compnoent U2 in the above circuit is [this](http://amzn.to/1NwHPHn)...

[image]

Note that this component type is highly orientation sensitive- high voltage AC feeds to the large flat metal parts on the body and the 12 DC is extracted from the round connector at the far end of the wire. Try not to connect backwards or it will likely not operate as expected.

Comment: Nope, that has a transformer. ;-)

Comment: Why do you have to ruin the fun for everyone?  :)

Comment: Two diodes, a potentiometer, done. Happy electrocuting to all customers of Kartik Rana...

Comment: I swear that was my 2nd answer! Along with a note to be sure to adjust the pot very quickly (50 or 60Hz) to keep up with the incoming AC wave. Swear. It would'a worked too... albeit with a touch of output ripple!